# IE6 NonSecure Items

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

So I'm chasing down the non-secure item on my page. I am using the JQuery library to make an accordion menu. I suspect that the  maybe the problem. Does anyone know if this href would be problematic? I can't find any blank src paths or http:.

Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The Jquery.ui library include  that do not specify a src attribute. IE6 will complain about this. The quick and dirty fix was to edit the library.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on where specifically you found and fixed this in the library?

Comment: Accepting your own answer without providing any details at all.  How helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a wordaround to the "non secure items" alert in IE8+.
The alert occurs if you are creating dynamic content with jQuery using wrap() or append() functions, and if this content contains CSS with relative paths to images, or any other external elements.

**Exemple :**

```
$('#mynode').wrap('<div style="background:url(/path/to/image.gif);"></div>');
```

This will display a security alert even if the image is downloaded on the same HTTPS secure connection.

**How to fix it :**

- Use full absolute URL :
  background:url('https://www.domain.com/path/to/image.gif');
- Or use CSS class :

> < style > .myclass
>   {background:url(/path/to/image.gif);} < /style >
>
> $('#mynode').wrap('< div class=myclass >< /div >');

Answer (score 0):

try opening the page in firefox and looking at the 
tools > page info > media tab.

this shows you all the media on the page and may give you a clue what is causing the non-secure error.

Josh

Comment: Thanks but all the images listed are https:

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'No'.. Href ='#' will not result in a non secure item warning in IE6.