# non-secure items in IE6

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer-6

my site is https and so I had to go through it and make sure everything on the page was secure. This worked for every browser except IE6, which gives an error saying that the page contains both secure and non-secure items. I cannot find a non-secure item on this page and it is driving me mad! Can anyone spot whats causing it?

The site is http://preview.tinyurl.com/4kk5u7q

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the JQuery library on your page?
Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060267/ie6-nonsecure-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try browsing the page (with Safari on OSX, in case it matters) I see that there are some resources which are described as `about:blank`. IIRC, IE6 thinks that that source is insecure. (I also get a syntax error in one of the inlined scripts.)

Comment: I agree. See http://gemal.dk/blog/2005/01/27/iframe_without_src_attribute_on_https_in_internet_explorer/ for more information.

Comment: can you tell me which resources it is that are described as this?

Comment: No, alas. I poked around for a while but couldn't work it out; I don't have very good web debug tools on this system (after all, I'm more of a server code guy).

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Chris.

This bug affects both **<FRAME>** and **<IFRAME>** element.

IE checks whether the attribute "src" points to a realistic page or not. It won't pass even if "src" attribute is simply missing. Try the followings:

1. Just create a blank page named "blank.html" or whatever you want.
2. Then you can point "src" attribute to the blank page when <FRAME> or <IFRAME> element is being created.

Example as below:

`<frame src="blank.html" id="foo" name="foo" >`

This should do the job;)